# Troubles with defining a macro n C++

Tags: c++, macros

Im trying to test this macro our teacher gave us and for some reason 
I keep getting a error messages. Does anyone know why? I can't seem to 
figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define die(errmsg) {cerr << errmsg << endl; exit(1);}
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int x;

    for(;;)
    {
        cout <<"How are you: " <endl;
        cout <<"1) good\n"; 
        cout <<"2) bad\n";

        cin >> x;

        if(x != 1 || x != 2)
            die("Invalid input");
    }



    return(0);
}
```

Comment: what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Did you forgot to include stdlib.h?

Comment: No, I get the same exact error and warning.

Comment: You realise that `if(x != 1 || x != 2)` evaluates to true for **all** values of `x` ?

Comment: Stuff like this (theres a lot more):

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:3894:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'const _CharT *' against
      'basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
operator< (const _CharT* __lhs,
^

1 warning and 1 error generated.

Comment: the error message would help and probably points you right to the offending line. Try adding the missing `<` on the first line inside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this loop:

```
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "How are you: " < endl;
    }
```

You're missing a `<` before `std::endl`

```
    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "How are you: " << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cout <<"How are you: " <endl;
```

You missed a `<` in the second `<<`